# Running functions on form data before/during validation in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Ok, so for example if someone is entering a username and I want to make it lowercase before OR at the beginning of validation (in my `rules` method) how can I do this?

I know you can do something similar with trim such as:

```
[['company_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'password2'], 'trim']
```

But I assume this doesn't support any function?

So, I would want to run the `strtolower` function on the username, what would be the way to go about doing this? Would I need to use the `beforeValidate` method or can I do something like this?

```
['username', 'makeLower']

public function makeLower($attribute, $params) {                
    $this->$attribute = strtolower($this->$attribute);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FilterValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filtervalidator.html).

```
['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'strtolower']
```

> FilterValidator is actually not a validator but a data processor. It
>   invokes the specified filter callback to process the attribute value
>   and save the processed value back to the attribute. The filter must be
>   a valid PHP callback with the following signature:
>
> ```
> function foo($value) {...return $newValue; }
> ```
>
> Many PHP functions qualify this signature (e.g. `trim()`).